# firebase database store list of items

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```js
    //1. Add menu items to the globalMenu and to restaurant, and the restaurantId of the restaurant adding menu.
    this.writeNewMenuItem = function(itemName, restaurantId) {
        // A post entry.
        var menuItem = {
            itemName: [itemName]
        };

        var ref = firebase.database().ref();

        // Get a key for a new Post.
        var newItem = ref
          .child('globalMenu')
          .push(menuItem);

        ref
          .child('restaurants')
          .child(restaurantId)
          //.child(newItem.key)
          .update(menuItem);

    }
```

1. Also let me know the way we can push and pop these items.
2. and if duplicate found this should not insert.
3. I want to fetch matched characters items, like if I pass 'app' in query this should return 'apple, application, appengine' etc. How could I do this?

Comment: There's a lot of unclarity here. What do you mean with "push and pop"? What defines a duplicate?

Comment: Push and Pop means I want to manage a list of items and in that I can add items and remove items..

Comment: The duplicate means, if the duplicate entry found in list it should not add that item.

Comment: What defined "a duplicate item"? If you don't want to store duplicate values, it's better to invert your array into a "set" like structure: `items: { "Pizza": true, "Coke": true }` With such a structure duplicates are automatically impossible and you won't have to scan a list (which doesn't scale and hurts multi-user concurrency).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid "arrays" in a Firebase Database, because:

> ... for distributed data, they aren't reliable because they lack a unique, permanent way to access each record.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Regarding your third question: querying the the database this way is not possible, you need to receive the whole list of all child nodes and do the filtering on the client side. I could recommend reading best practices for structuring the data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's probably best to use a sub-collection (you can add and delete using the identifier of the document), similarly to what you have for "restaurants", but specifying your custom "document id", which could be "pizza", "burger", etc. But keeping an unused field inside each document so that it does not get automatically deleted by firebase (the field I recommend is a void type to save space).

```
db.collection("cities").doc("pizza").set({x: null})
```

When you read, you can access the document id